# VB.NET Changing Colors for each line in a error message

Tags: vb.net, colors, msg

Hi I created an error message that contains each value of whether or not is was a pass or fail. I would like each entry to change color based on Passed = green and pail = red.

Example:

1. Fare: Passed
2. Name: Passed
3. Date: Failed
4. Address: Failed
5. Age: Passed

This gets displayed in an output message box, currently

```
msgBox(errorMessage)
```

When this gets displayed I like the fails background to be red and the passed to have a 
green background.
Currently I am still considered new to VB.Net I know how to do for mouse hovers and mouseleaves. I am assuming I need to make an event similar to those.

Thank you For your help.

Comment: That's not an option, you'll need at least a RichTextBox to display text with a choice of colors.

Comment: If you are trying to present something like Data Validation results, consider the [ErrorProvider](http://i.imgur.com/mu68SYI.jpg) component which will display a message when you hover over an item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not going to do that with `MsgBox` or `MessageBox.Show`, which `MsgBox` calls internally.  You're going to have to create your own form and then either add one `Label` for each line, in which case you can set the `ForeColor` for each one, or else draw the text yourself using GDI+.  If you do go the `Label` route, you'll probably want to use a `TableLayoutPanel` or `FlowLayoutPanel` to keep them aligned correctly.

Comment: Can't we make our own message box? And change the colours of the text that way?

Comment: Um, that's what I said.  What exactly would your own message box be if not a form of your own creation?  What do you think it is that `MsgBox` and `MessageBox.Show` actually display?  It's a form.  You need to create the form yourself because the one that those methods display cannot be manipulated to change the text colour.